# Websocket connection lost every 15min with Azure and XSockets.net

Tags: sockets, azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services, xsockets.net

I deployed my XSockets.net server to a worker role in Microsoft Azure. Since then every 15min my clients loose connection to the server and will reconnect to the server again. Which works very well. But on server side, the sockets aren't closed and the status of the sockets are still open and connected.

I'm using XScoets.net in version 5.0.1. I'm not sure if this happens because of the load balancer in between, which cancels the connection to the client, not to the server, though. On implementation side there are keep alive messages (ping/pong within the XSockets server). Also having high traffic during these 15min the connection will break up.

The problem is also that after few hours of running the server has hundreds up to thousands open connections which consumes a lot of resources and the implemented connection management is not able to do it's job because he tries to request clients that doesn't exist.

Do you have had similar issues or have an idea where to investigate? Very difficult to tell why this happen. No exceptions or disconnect reasons occurs.

Comment: What protocol are you using for communication, and what type of client (javascript, C# or something else)? If you do not know what protocol you use I will assume websockets.

Comment: Server and client are implemented in C#. Yes we use the websockets protocol. Binding/Endpoint is https/wss